# Static assertion of `is_base_of` in templated class fails with unexpected type in MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, generic-programming

I want to make sure that one of the template parameters of my class is derived of a specific (abstract) class. With this intention is wrote this

```
class abstract_record
    {};
        template<typename Record, typename Container = std::vector>  //requires SequenceContainer<Container> //See ISO/IEC PRF TS 19217
    class mddb_adapter : public Wt::WAbstractTableModel
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<abstract_record, Record>,"Record must be derived of MDDB_Service::MDDB_Web::abstract_record");
...
```

But I get a compiler error:

> `error C2226: syntax error : unexpected type 'std::is_base_of<abstract_record,Record>'`

Is this a problem of MSVC (I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express) or did I got something wrong, e.g. how do I solve this?

Comment: you are missing suffix `::value`, namely `std::is_base_of<abstract_record, Record>::value`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That should be an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of the `is_base_of` verification is accessible via a static nested `value` data member:

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<abstract_record, Record>::value
//                                                    ~~~~~~^
     , "Record must be derived of MDDB_Service::MDDB_Web::abstract_record");
```

If your compiler supports constexpr evaluation of a conversion operator, you can instead use the below syntax:

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<abstract_record, Record>{}
//                                                    ↑↑
     , "Record must be derived of MDDB_Service::MDDB_Web::abstract_record");
```

Comment: That's embarrassing, I had used ::value but got some other errors at that time, and later removed it, because I thought the `operator bool` member function of is_base_of would lead to the same behavior.

Comment: @Superlokkus `std::is_base_of<abstract_record, Record>{}` would trigger implicit conversion to `bool`, `std::is_base_of<abstract_record, Record>` itself won't, it's just a type name